# IORef still refers to the old value after update

Tags: haskell, io, scheme, ioref

## Background

I am a Schemer starting to learn Haskell. I am trying to implement a Scheme interpreter in C, following [chapter 4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-25.html#%_chap_4) of SICP. It turns out programming directly in C is too hard. So I decide to first prototype in Haskell. With the help of [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours), I have implemented everything except variables, closures and environment.

## Problem

The modification to `IORef` doesn't persist between invocations of `main`. I expect the program to print **(False) (True) (True) (True)**... but in fact it prints **(False) (True) (False) (True) (False) (True)**...

Strip-down version of the code:

```hs
import Data.IORef

data SCM = Environment (IORef Bool) SCM | Empty'Environment

global :: IO SCM
global = Environment <$> newIORef False <*> pure Empty'Environment

print'' :: SCM -> IO ()
print'' ls =
  case ls of
    Empty'Environment -> pure ()
    Environment first rest -> readIORef first >>= putStr . show >> print'' rest

print' :: SCM -> IO ()
print' ls = putStr "(" *> print'' ls *> putStrLn ")"

main :: IO ()
main = global >>=
       \ls -> case ls of
                Empty'Environment -> pure ()
                Environment first _ -> print' ls *>
                                       modifyIORef first (const True) *>
                                       print' ls *>
                                       main
```

Syntax-highlighted version:
[image: ioref.hs]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `global` create new `SCM` with new `IORef`. You should reorganize your loop, where `global` will be performed once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can cut your example down to `main = (global >>= loop) >> main`. The problem is that `global` is not a single global variable, instead its a `IO SCM`, an action that will create the global value. Let us rename it:

```
createSCM :: IO SCM
createSCM = Environment <$> newIORef False <*> pure Empty'Environment
```

Now the name is closer to the truth. We create a new `SCM` every time we call that function. So your program works like this:

```
main = (createSCM >>= loop) >> main
     = (createSCM >>= loop) >> (createSCM >>= loop) >> main
     = (createSCM >>= loop) >> (createSCM >>= loop) >> ...
```

As you can see we create new `SCM` all the time. Therefore you don't get the expected behavior.

The solution is simple. Create your `global` and `loop` explicitly:

```
main = do
  global <- createSCM
  let loop = do
         ...
         loop
  loop
```

Comment: Thank you, so my misconception was to think of it as a global. But in fact, it behaves more like a constructor, right?

Comment: @AlexVong right. You can think of any `IO a` as an _action_ that will yield an `a` if executed. For example, `readLine :: IO String` will give you a `String` when you execute it, yet you don't expect `readLine` to return the same string for every call (it depends on the user's input).